# Anyone beta testing the nomad?

Tags: gear, equipment

So I know this thread is on many other sites, specifically jwsound, but I would like to get the take from post audio minded people, not just production sound guys.  I am looking at the Nomad 6 pretty seriously instead of a 744/442 combo.

My main concern was max sample rate, but it has been said that 96k is possible and 192 is possible with track limitations.

I take production sound/eng gigs on the side to supplement my post endeavors until they increase to the point of sustaining me financially, so having a mixer is great.

Anyone have any thoughts/ideas on the nomad and how it may not be what I am looking for.  I considered the 552 until I found out of the sample rate cap and not being able to name files.  The naming convention has not really crept into any thread so I am assuming you can name all your files and tracks accordingly since so many Film mixers are considering them and purchasing them.

I am looking at doing the upgrade to something with at least four recording tracks.  With the 744 I still have to purchase additional preamps to utilize 3/4, so the price range of a 744/442 combo is right in the area of the nomad 6.  I would love to get something bigger and more tracks like the 788 or deva of some form, but I cannot quite justify that purchase.

What are your thoughts on the Nomad and what may be some things I am overlooking? It seems like the perfect solution for me,  high inputs for eng mixing, and ability to multitrack record when I am doing sfx recordings.

Answer (score 1):

Where have you heard that it is capable of 96/192? I'm curious, since the specs page on Zaxcom's website lists a max of 48.048.

From what I can tell, it's targeted at production recordists/mixers who don't need the higher sample rate recording. 24/48 is still pretty much defacto for dialogue recording. So, if you're concerned about getting higher sample rates for effects recording, this may not be the best route for you.

That being said, Zaxcom makes some great gear. We have a Deva 5.8 at work. Overkill for some things (why we have a 744T+302 combo), but great when you need a whole mess-o-channels.

Comment: I agree with Shaun about its intended use, but a rep I spoke with at AES in Vegas said 96k might be possible at some point, but was catty about if that'd be the case at launch. It'd be pretty easy to cannibalize you own sales if one were to go too far... ;-)

Comment: @Shaun somewhere in the massive threads on JWsound.net I read that Glenn Trew commented on the sample rate thing.  The website has not been updated due to beta testing still occurring and changes being made constantly, I am not sure if it is 100 percent true, because it is something most of the production sound guys are just glossing over.

Comment: @Shaun I also would love a 744T especially if it just had four preamps in the dang thing, just a pain to have to buy both recorder and mixer to utilize the recorder.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need an assistant?

Comment: @chris I wish I had the work load to need an assistant.  If your in my area though I will keep in mind if it ends up happening.

Comment: You should put this as a comment to his question, not an answer :-) 